# Android Import java.util.StringJoiner error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I tried to import `java.util.StringJoiner` but I received this message

`Usage of API documented as @since 1.8+ less... (⌘F1) 
This inspection finds all usages of methods that have @since tag in their documentation.  This may be useful when development is performed under newer SDK version as the target platform for production.`

i'm using :

java version "1.8.0_102"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)

How to solve this problem. Thank you all for helping me!!

Comment: you can not run an android app with java 8... your sdk is maybe 1.8 but the JVM is not allowing that version

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ : So I must downgrade java ?

Comment: @ThoNguyen, No but you can't use `Java 8 only features`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StringJoiner` was added in API Level 24. If your `minSdkVersion` is 24 or higher (i.e., will only run on Android 7.0+), you are welcome to use it. If your `minSdkVersion` is lower than 24, either replace your use of `StringJoiner` entirely or only use it on devices running API Level 24 or higher.

The specific message that you are getting is because not only was this class introduced in API Level 24, but it came from Java 8. Older devices do not support Java 8 classes.

Also, Java 8 functionality requires the Jack compiler, which at the present time is not the default compiler. You will need to follow [the instructions to enable Java 8 support in Gradle](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html#configure-gradle), adding the `jackOptions` and `compileOptions` closures:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.commonsware.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to change `minSdkVerion 24` and install all sdk packet 7.0. But still not working. :'(

Comment: @ThoNguyen: It will be easier to help you if you explain, in detail, what "But still not working" means.

Comment: Thank you. I still see this warning "Usage of API documented as @since 1.8+ less... (⌘F1) " and can't import java.util.StringJoiner.

Comment: @ThoNguyen: You also need to set up Java 8 support in Gradle. See the updated answer.

Comment: OMG. Thank you very much. I'm a newbie in android. You save my life <3